# how get find serial number between serial range

Tags: oracle

I have to filter serial number set but in the database have a serial range only. how can i get serial range?

Example: This my oracle DB

```
Agent ID    Date          From_serial     To_serial
123         12/12/2015     345643145      345643400
234         11/12/2105     234563423      234563700
```

I have a serial list like this

```
345643150
345643151
```

so need to filter this serial in which range

Comment: You can use `between`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select y.*,s.ser
from your_table_name y,
     (select 345643150 as ser from dual
     union all
     select 345643151 as ser from dual) s
where s.ser between y.from_serial and y.to_serial
```

Comment: i am getting all range @dianoti, if from_serial , to_serial number 34 to 36 that is also filter.

Comment: @ need to set length size also (my serial number length is 9)

Comment: And I have 30 serial number list . is there any way to get in one shot rather than search one by one serial number?

Comment: you need to be more specific. do you have those serial numbers with you or getting from some table ? if you have your serial numbers(that you want to search) in a table, you can replace the subquery with select from that table.

Comment: serial number with me(there are around 30 serial numbers) not to getting from some table

Comment: Then you need to create a query like one created above. I created for 2, you need to write 30 UNION ALL statements. or you can fire 30 queries, one for each serial number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from tab where '345643150' between  From_serial  AND    To_serial
```

Comment: i am getting all range @dianoti, if from_serial , to_serial number 34 to 36 that is also filter.

Comment: i need to consider the serial length also (serial length is 9)